# Foursquare Api function venuesPhotos is returning null

Tags: java, eclipse, foursquare

I'm trying to use the following function of FoursquareApi in my java program in Eclipse:

```
foursquareApi.venuesPhotos(venue.getId(), "venue", 100, 5);
```

However the results returned by the function is null although the code returned is 200. Can you please tell me the cause or reason why the result is null? Is it inaccessible from foursquare Api anymore? Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you sure the venue has photos available? You can check on the web at http://foursquare.com/<VENUE_ID>

Comment: Now it works... It was a problem with setting the appropriate parameters. Thanks for your answer!!